# rook-haunted as applied to an interior room

Tags: meaning-in-context, metaphors

In the book I’m reading the author writes:

> The Russian clergy had little in common with the Anglican curates and
>   bishops in whose paneled libraries and **rook-haunted** chambers James
>   passed some of his winter evenings.

So, *rook-haunted*. 
Googling shows that it’s not a rare word combination. But in most cases it seems to be understood quite literally – “rook-haunted groves” or “rook-haunted towers,” which can be imagined as groves or walls, well, “frequented” by the birds.

But I suspect the rook is not the only bird species that can be met in any environment. And you’re unlikely to meet any bird at all in a chamber where you pass evenings.

My question has thus two points:

1. What does “rook-haunted” mean as applied to an interior room?
2. Since it’s apparently a metaphor, where does it come from? Some classic work everyone knows? Some folk text? Something else?

Comment: I disagree with 'Googling shows that it’s not a rare word combination'. The few examples I've seen are literal usages, and there are too few for this to be an idiom. Examples of 'rook-haunted churches' shows that it's not fanciful to consider rooks roosting within big old buildings, and living quarters for curates and bishops in those days would probably qualify.

Comment: Well, perhaps "not a rare..." was an exaggeration, but few dozens (especially as combined with the search of "haunted by rooks") came to make me think that it's an image from a text I'm unaware of. Your comment was helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I needed more context of the story and found it [here](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=THeoseRjlP0C&pg=PA106&lpg=PA106&dq=Russian%20clergy#v=onepage&q=Russian%20clergy&f=false).

1. I think the author (George Steiner), wants you to imagine an old, high vaulted room where rooks may have nested long ago.
2. I know not, of any metaphor where "rook-haunted" comes from... although when googled, it shows images of old manor houses with crows (or rooks) in the foreground.

It looks like a really good book!

Comment: Yes, the image in my mind was exactly like that. I just thought that this phrase has something more in meaning (and vision) for a native English speaker than for me.